# Upload 4 images separately , Rails 4 + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I want to upload 4 photos separately. Like there is 1 button for each photo upload.

At this moment I have fully working multiple photo upload, but it is very unpleasant to work with. Because you can't browse folders to select each photo from different folder. All photos has to be in one place.
This is for multiple image upload from single location/folder.
**In view:**

```
 <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

**In controller:**

```
  def create
  @advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params.merge(service_ids: params[:service_ids], hour_ids: params[:hour_ids]))

    if @advertisement.save
     if params[:images]

         params[:images].each { |image|  #this line !!
           @advertisement.pictures.create(image: image)  #this line !!
        } 
         respond_with(@advertisement)
      end        
    else
       @services = Service.all    
       @country = Country.all
       @hours = Hour.all
       @regions = Region.where("country_id = ?", Country.first.id)
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

I tried to change form to:

```
            <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false %>
            <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false %>
            <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false %>
            <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false %>
```

Tried to upload, but that wasn't succesful.
I checked log file, where I can see that application tried to upload 4 separate files, but that didn't work out.

```
 "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003de9650 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141230-13530-qd0gk4>, @original_filename="DSCF0265.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"DSCF0265.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003de9628 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141230-13530-1pvtd4q>, @original_filename="DSCF0173.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"DSCF0173.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003de9600 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141230-13530-9tomtw>, @original_filename="DSCF0202.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"DSCF0202.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]
```

Then I tried to change for to:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

then I got error :unknown attribute: image when I tried to create.

Any tips or help ?

Comment: What is your attachment called in your advertisement model?

Comment: @NickM In advertisement model I have like this ` has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy `and then in Picture model  `has_attached_file :image`

Comment: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/

Comment: Can you post the whole form, please?

Comment: I solved issue. I had to use `<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false %>` but there was model validation that didn't show error, but It should. Now it works.